# lvalue required as left operand of assignment (not a "use == " )

Tags: function, pointers, function-pointers, lvalue

I have a lvalue operand problem when trying to assign a function pointer. I don't know where the problem is exactly, but I'll give you all the code that has to do with that specific problem.

```
    double *func(double); //initialization for a pointer to a function that both returns a double and requires a double

    func = &xsquaredsinx; //trying to make the pointer point at a function that both returns a double and requires a double
    func = &halfcircle;//others that are the same
    func = &testfunction;
```

Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for `func`'s declaration is incorrect; that declaration declares a function that takes a `double` and returns a `double*`.  The correct way to declare `func` is:

```
double (*func)(double);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the exact problem, and now it's fixed. Two hours on a simple syntax error :P Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your declaration `double *func(double);` does not declare a pointer to a function but just declares a function. Try instead `double (*func)(double);`

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#assign